# Filter dates to only first of the month (in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, that contains a mix of dates. However, I would like to filter my dataset to only include the dates for the first of the month. I can easily do this in Excel, but I wish to implement this logic using Python.

```
date          id
 
10/01/2020    a
10/01/2020    a
10/24/2020    a
10/26/2020    a
11/01/2020    b
11/24/2020    b
11/01/2020    b
```

Desired output

```
date         id
 
10/01/2020    a
10/01/2020    a
11/01/2020    b
11/01/2020    b
```

This is what I am doing:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy  as np

 df1 = pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2020-01-01',freq='Months')
```

I am not getting the expected output with the code above. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas, but I would expect that filter to allow any date between 2019-01-01 and 2020-01-01, so that would explain why you didn't get the results you wanted.

Comment: @QuangHoang The desired output includes two rows with id `a` and two rows with id `b`, so I'm not sure dropping duplicate id's will work.

Comment: hm ok I have it set to: pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2020-01-01',freq='Months') - I will try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform()` to extract the min dates, then use boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'),'id'])
         .date.transform('min') == df['date']
      ]
```

That would give you the rows with minimum dates for each month. However, if you want exactly the first (e.g. oct 1st), you just need to check the day:

```
df.loc[df.date.dt.day==1]
```

Comment: ah @quang hoang this makes sense to take the min of the value. Ok I will try this now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Given some timeseries dataframe df, and a column, "date", with datetimes in it, something like this will work:

```
df[df["date"].dt.day == 1]
```

Where the datetime is in the index, something like this will work:

```
df[df.index.day == 1]
```